# Is HTML Speech recognition free

Tags: speech-recognition

The Speechrecognition browser API allows web pages to capture audio and transcribe the result into input fields.  The draft specification says that using this feature in Chrome results in audio being sent to Google servers for analysis. But is this service free or charged?  Google, Azure etc all have cloud speech to text services that are charged, but they require direct API calls which are not happening when using the DOM interfaces.

What happens if the user is using an alternative browser (when they offer speech recognition) - will each browser use that vendors speech APIs.  The spec has a ServiceURI component, will we need to point that to our preferred cloud API vendor?

On some mobile devices you automatically get an optional microphone for most html input fields, even without explicitly using the speech API.

What I find confusing is that I understand quality recognition requires cloud services, but aren't keen to subscribe to multiple recognition engines. And it isn't clear if I need too. There isn't any talk around limits of browser generated speech recogntion - could someone transcribe hours of speech, without using paid cloud services?  Many of our end users will love speech interface and will generate lots of short snipets of audio a month, so need to understand potential cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is this service free or charged?

It is free

> What happens if the user is using an alternative browser (when they offer speech recognition) - will each browser use that vendors speech APIs.

It simply does not work in many other browsers

> There isn't any talk around limits of browser generated speech recogntion - could someone transcribe hours of speech, without using paid cloud services?

There is a timeout after 5 minutes (300 seconds)